# How to call grails remoteFunction with multiple parameters?

Tags: ajax, grails

I have 3 GSP `<g:select ...>` tags...

1) `<g:select id="brandList" name="brand.id" from="${com.awnsys.retail.Brand.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${usedPurchaseInstance?.brand?.id}" />`

2) `<g:select id="typeList" name="type.id" from="${com.awnsys.retail.Type.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${usedPurchaseInstance?.type?.id}" />`

3) `<g:select id="modelList" name="modelNo.id" from="${com.awnsys.retail.Model.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${usedPurchaseInstance?.modelNo?.id}" />`

the 3rd `<g:select>` tag will be loaded based on values of 1st and 2nd `<g:select>` tags.

In Model Domain class code is:

```
class Model {
   String name    
   static belongsTo = [brand:Brand, type:Type]
    static constraints = {
    }   
String toString() { name }
}
```

How to load the 3rd `g:select` tab based on the 1st and 2nd and post controller code for the same.

Comment: You should show a result od your effort to make it work. What did you try? What specific problem were you facing?

Comment: You can simple use jquery ajax no need remoteFunction, 

e.g. $.ajax({url: g.link('controller', 'action'), data: {param1: param1, param2: param2} etc